# Small Images optimization

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, optimization, small-image

When I check my Magento store with **Page-speed** I am always recommended with **Optimize Images**, when I open the list of images to be optimized all those images are the **small images** of the products.
Is there any solution where I can optimize **small images** of my products?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for image optimisation by reducing the size ( in bytes ) of image. These following tools can be installed on the server

- jpegoptim - for jpeg images
- optipng - for png images
- gifsicle - for gif images
- guetzli for jpeg images

There are following APIs available today which allow you to optimise images -:

- TinyJPG | https://tinypng.com/
- Compressor.io
- Kraken.io
- ImageOptimizer
- ImageOptim
- Resmush

As you can see there are several tools and APIs are available which allows you to deal with optimisation of the product images not only for Magento website but for any other website.

There are several extensions available in the market to help you integrate with the above APIs out of these extensions we have used the following -:

https://www.scommerce-mage.com/optimize-magento-product-cms-images.html

The above extension integrates with the following APIs -:

- Kraken.io
- ImageOptim
- Resmush.it

Then we have fishpig extension which integrated only with Resmush.it

https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/extensions/smush-it/

and Apptrian extension which not sure which APIs they use but they do use guetzli

https://www.apptrian.com/image-optimizer-for-magento

Hope the above information helps